# Is it legal for a coroutine's promise_type to lack both return_void and return_value, if the execution doesn't fall off the end of the coroutine body?

Tags: c++, return, language-lawyer, c++20, c++-coroutine

It is possible that a coroutine is such that it `co_yield`s values in an endless `while(true)`, in which case it'll never fall off the end of its body, so it will not need to call `return_value`, nor `rerturn_void`.

This makes me think that indeed it is perfectly valid for a coroutine's `promise_type` not to declare either of those functions.

The standard indeed [says that](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.fct.def.coroutine#6)

> If searches for the names `return_void` and `return_value` in the scope of the promise type each find any declarations, the program is ill-formed.

The way I understand it, the it can be rephrased (in a more elementar English?) as

> If in the scope of the promise type both the search for the name `return_void` find a declaration, and the search for the name `return_value` finds one or more declarations, the program is ill-formed.

i.e. you cannot declare both `return_void` and `return_value` in a promise type.

However, that says nothing about `return_void` and `return_value` both missing. I would therefore assume it's fine, but I'm asking here for confirmation, in case I've not really understood what I've read in the draft.

Comment: I understand specs as : the promise_type must have return_void or return_value. So you clearly cannot have none of them. But it is not clear if both is allowed.
Having both suppose you can have 2 possible types of result, so for me it's unconsistent

Comment: @dalfaB: "*the promise_type must have return_void or return_value*" That's not what the literal text says.